# How to tell which video failed to download from a youtube playlist using youtube-dl

Tags: youtube-dl

I've been using youtube-dl for a while now to batch download playlists.

Sometimes, youtube-dl begins to run, and prints a message like "getting 200 video id's, downloading 199 of them" - or something like that.

1 video is missing (199 of 200 successful). Is there any way to find out which one(s) failed?

Answer (score 0):

The numbers in the output [are a result of](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/d66152a8982261f930c2a324c1fc3ba3b3324134/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py#L559) `--playlist-start` and `--playlist-end`. If you're passing in neither option, then the output should always be `200 of 200`. If you're passing them in, check the values. Pass in `1` for playliststart and `None` (or `-1` in older versions) for playlistend to get the whole list.

If that does not solve your problem, then post the entire output, then [create an issue in the youtube-dl issuetracker](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/issues/new). Please include the entire output of a problematic download, and pass in the `--verbose` option to youtube-dl. This allows the developers to find where your problem is.